# ioctl() invocation with 'SIOCGIWNAME' returns EOPNOTSUPP for wireless interface

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-networking, network-interface, android-wireless

I'm trying to run the following code in the native stack of my app on *Pixel 6* running *Android 13*. Unfortunately, the `ioctl()` API invocation for the wireless interface **wlan0** is returning error code **95** (EOPNOTSUPP).

```
​bool isWireless()
{
    int sock;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error opening socket, code: %d", errno);
        return false;
    }

    struct iwreq pwrq;
    memset(&pwrq, 0, sizeof(pwrq));
    strncpy(pwrq.ifr_name, "wlan0", IFNAMSIZ);

    int retCode = ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &pwrq);
    if (retCode != -1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    printf("Error getting wireless proto, code: %d", errno);

    return false;
}
```

​Note that the command 'adb shell ifconfig' returns with the following output

```
lo        Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0 

dummy0    Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b8ee:36ff:fe51:a535/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:840 

wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC  
          inet addr:192.168.25.91  Bcast:192.168.25.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::8f0:61ff:feed:4ec5/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:6077 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7476175 TX bytes:1815514
```

Also, the command 'adb shell ip addr show' returns the following

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:ee:36:51:a5:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::b8ee:36ff:fe51:a535/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether 9e:4b:e5:02:26:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether b2:fe:7b:dc:c0:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: erspan0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
10: ip6_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1364 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
11: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
12: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
13: ip6gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre6 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
14: rmnet0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
15: rmnet1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
16: rmnet2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
17: rmnet3: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
18: rmnet4: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
19: rmnet5: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
20: rmnet6: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
21: rmnet7: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
22: rmnet8: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
23: rmnet9: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
24: rmnet10: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
25: rmnet11: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
26: rmnet12: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
27: rmnet13: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
28: rmnet14: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
29: rmnet15: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
30: rmnet16: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
31: rmnet17: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
32: rmnet18: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
33: rmnet19: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
34: rmnet20: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
35: rmnet21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
36: rmnet22: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
37: rmnet23: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
38: rmnet24: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
39: rmnet25: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
40: rmnet26: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
41: rmnet27: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
42: rmnet28: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
43: rmnet29: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
44: dummy: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
46: aware_nmi0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:4c:33:22:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
47: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:f0:61:ed:4e:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.25.91/24 brd 192.168.25.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8f0:61ff:feed:4ec5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
48: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b2:21:09:31:86:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
49: dit0: <> mtu 2560 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[519] 
50: radiotap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

​It is expected that the API invocation `ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &pwrq)` shown in the code snippet above will succeed.

Could you guys confirm why the API is behaving differently?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Maybe you are not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567125. Also, this works fine in Ubuntu and returns the result as expected.